# How to CSS triangle at the bottom and center it in div ( Horizontal Menubar )?

Tags: html, css

How to CSS triangle at the bottom and center it in div ( Horizontal Menubar )?

Menubar width is 100%;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/leonyipwh/Yggbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to your CSS for `li`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yggbc/1/)

```
li {
    display: table-cell;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    position:relative; /* <-- this */
}
```

You may also want to revise some of the rest of your CSS thus:

```
#bar {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block; /* <-- make the items appear on the same row, you shouldnt be using displace:table-cell */
}
.btn.selected {
    color: black !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #f7eee7;
}
.btn:hover:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left:calc(50% - 9px); /* <-- ensure your triangles are centered */
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 9px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add `position:relative` to the `.btn` class

To center the arrow you will need to add either a negative left margin equivalent to half it's width or use a CSS3 transform.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/Yggbc/4/)

**CSS**

```
#bar {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.btn {
    position: relative;
}
.btn:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 9px solid black;
    display: none;
}
.btn:hover:after {
    display: block;
}
.btn.selected {
    color: black !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #f7eee7;
}
```